# How can I use Qt5 connect() on a slot with default parameters

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, qt5, signals-slots

I have some code that looks something like this:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void SetValue(float value);

public slots:
    void OnSetValue(float value, bool fromDatabase = false);
}

connect(this, SIGNAL(SetValue(float)), this, SLOT(OnSetValue(float)));
```

This works fine but I want to take advantage of [Qt5's new signal/slot syntax](https://woboq.com/blog/new-signals-slots-syntax-in-qt5.html) (and remove the macros). If I change the connect() to this:

```
connect(this, &MyClass::SetValue, this, &MyClass::OnSetValue);
```

I get (in Visual Studio 2013):

> error C2338: The slot requires more arguments than the signal provides

I could create an intermediary function that calls OnSetValue() and allows the default parameters to be set but that seems like a waste of code. What's a better way of solving this?

Comment: According to Qt wiki, it's not possible with member function pointers: https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax#cons.

Comment: `connect(this, &MyClass::SetValue, [this](float value){OnSetValue(value);});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [link](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax#cons) that [sim642](https://stackoverflow.com/users/854540/sim642) provided also stated that the new connect syntax "can be used with c+11 lambda expressions". For the above example I was able to use:

```
connect(this, &MyClass::SetValue, [=](float value) { OnSetValue(value); });
```

which is slightly more complicated but is less code than adding an intermediary function and does still provide compile-time checking.

[Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) provided a better version above:

```
connect(this, &MyClass::SetValue, [this](float value){ OnSetValue(value); });
```

This replaces [=] (enables the lambda to capture all the automatic variables in scope by value) with [this], reducing the scope of the lambda and the possibility of error.